# How do I set the right return type in M code function?

Tags: powerbi, m

I got this function in M code to extract data from a webservice, but I get the error:

> Expression.Error: Vi kan ikke konvertere en værdi af typen Binary til typen Table.

How do I set the correct datatype for the returnvalue?

```
(getInvoiceLines as text,FromYear as text,ToYear as text,FromMonth as text,ToMonth as text, ToDay as text) as table =>

let

      Kilde = Web.Contents("https://odata.uniconta.com/odata/DebtorInvoiceLines?$filter=Date ge datetime'"&FromYear&"-"&FromMonth&"-01T00:00:00' and Date le datetime'"&FromYear&"-"&FromMonth&"-"&ToDay&"T00:00:00'", [Headers=[Authorization = getInvoiceLines ]])
    //Kilde = OData.Feed("https://odata.uniconta.com/odata/DebtorInvoiceLines?$filter=Date ge datetime'"&FromYear&"-"&FromMonth&"-01T00:00:00' and Date le datetime'"&FromYear&"-"&FromMonth&"-"&ToDay&"T00:00:00'", null, [Headers=[Authorization = getInvoiceLines ]])
in
    Kilde
```

Comment: Perhaps [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69511023/edit) a translation of the error message? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the return type `as table` from the function definition.

Comment: If I use the first option the editor returns type-id not valid.

Comment: If I use the second, I get "Expression.Error: Can't convert type Binary to type List.
Detaljer:
    Value=[Binary]
    Type=[Type]